# Are there addons to assist with Archaeology?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

What are some addons, if any, that assist with archaeology?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- [Archy](http://wow.curse.com/downloads/wow-addons/details/archy.aspx)
- [Archaeology Helper](http://www.wowinterface.com/downloads/info19037-ArchaeologyHelper.html)
- [Gathermate 2](http://wow.curse.com/downloads/wow-addons/details/gathermate2.aspx)

[Example usage.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vBNOqXfr1aM)

As you survey, your HUD will show you which zone you should try your next survey in. If you have Gathermate data already or if you install an existing database, you'll see dots on your HUD as well that show known artifact locations. Typically, you go to the colored zone in your HUD, then you try surveying on the existing dots in the new zone. If you are lucky or have a good database, one of those dots will have the artifact. If you are told you are close but none of the dots gives you an artifact, then you're very near where you need to be and you should keep surveying as normally would.

There is a [Gathermate 2 database](http://wow.curse.com/downloads/wow-addons/details/gathermate2_data.aspx) released by the authors that can get you started. Follow the instructions on the page to get it installed.

Answer (score 5):

Try [Archy](http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/archy).

Comment: Hi! As you can see, you'll get way more upvotes if you write a more comprehensive answer, rather than just a link!